# Why is Makefile always the gist's cover file and how to prevent it?

Tags: makefile, gist

I've learned to add the `_` prefix in the file I want to be the cover of my gist, e.g.,

[image]

However, when my gist also have `Makefile`, for some reason, it becomes the cover file, e.g. (in this gist, I do have a file prefixed with `_`, but `Makefile` appears as the cover file)

[image]